# Sharepoint Fast Search, long response time on first query

Tags: fast-search

In my SharePoint Fast Search, when I search "something" for the first time it takes 10 seconds (heavy time), but if I search again for the same word it takes 2 seconds.
Why for the first time it is taking more time. It's a performance degrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the accuracy index of refinement panel from 500 to 50 and now i get results fast enough

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that after a longer period of no activity, components in SharePoint and on the FS4SP servers will be flushed to disk. The solution is to have a keep alive task running at regular intervals which makes sure the system is fresh.

In most live systems this is not that big an issue as search queries are executed quite frequently.